# SW6 product patch - replace all data

Tags: shopware6-api

Is there a way to remove alle object-links from a product via admin-API in SW6?
All cross-selling, media, propertygroup, etc. without naming each and every single object?

Like when creating articles the first time. Currently and because of deleting so many links between article, cross-selling-articles, propertygroups, etc. it takes way too much time to upload ~ 4.100 articles by API.

Thanks in advance.

I tried deleting every propertygroup-option, every media-entry, every cross-selling-article, because in our ERP the customer can just do so. Change the order of images, change values in propertygroup-options, link new products or remove links. So we came to a point where a complete resync is way less overhead than checking each and every change and having the API flooded with calls all the time.

As I understood in SW5 there was the possibility to do a PATCH on products to overwrite it's data.
Now we ask the API which elements are currently linked just to send a remove call afterwards and another links-call.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no implemented way to solve this. You would need the related ids and when sending a DELETE request.

Comment: That makes all tasts difficult and quite not easy to accomplish. I discovered that my media-routines checking if an image is in the media folder sometimes return false. So images being there get overwritten changing it's paths. That is not only a problem for the SEO, but also results in 404-errors in order-confirmation-mails. Links do not exists any more. Do you have an idea how to solve this?